# Guidance with implementation of TreeSet's get method. (Homework)

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree, treeset

Okay so the professor wants me to implement the get method for my TreeSet class. He gave me an algorithm as a guideline to implement the get method:

> get(k)
>
> Start from the tree root and let M be the number of nodes in its left
>   subtree.
>
> (1) If M equals k-1, then the root is the node you're looking for.
>
> (2) If M is less than k, then the node you're looking for must be in
>   the right subtree. When we move to the right subtree, we have to
>   subtract M+1 from k. Now the right subtree becomes the new root, and
>   you repeat the process.
>
> (3) If M is greater than k, you have to check for the node in the left
>   subtree.

I tried implementing the method both ways, recursively and iteratively (I don't know how to spell it). Here is the entire class code below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import sun.misc.Queue;

/**
 * Binary Search Tree that inherits from the TreeSet class
 * The class is based on Weiss's non-generic implementation of BinarySearchTree
 * 
 * @author Daniel
 * @param <T> 
 */
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> extends TreeSet<T> implements Iterable<T> 
{
    /**
     * Construct the tree.
     */
    public BinarySearchTree( )
    {
        root = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T e)
    {
        insert(e);
        return true;
    }



    /**
     * Insert into the tree; duplicates are ignored.
     * @param x the item to insert.
     */
    public void insert( Comparable x )
    {        
        {

            root = insert( x, root );   

        }

    }

    /**
     * Remove from the tree. Nothing is done if x is not found.
     * @param x the item to remove.
     */
    public void remove( Comparable<T> x )
    {

        root = remove( x, root );


    }

    /**
     * Find the smallest item in the tree.
     * @return smallest item or null if empty.
     */
    public Comparable findMin( )
    {
        return elementAt( findMin( root ) );
    }

    /**
     * Find the largest item in the tree.
     * @return the largest item of null if empty.
     */
    public Comparable findMax( )
    {
        return elementAt( findMax( root ) );
    }

    /**
     * Find an item in the tree.
     * @param x the item to search for.
     * @return the matching item or null if not found.
     */
    public Comparable find( Comparable x )
    {
        return elementAt( find( x, root ) );
    }

    /**
     * Make the tree logically empty.
     */
    public void makeEmpty( )
    {
        root = null;
    }

    /**
     * Test if the tree is logically empty.
     * @return true if empty, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty( )
    {
        return root == null;
    }

    /**
     * Print the tree contents in sorted order.
     */
    public void printTree( )
    {
        if( isEmpty( ) )
            System.out.println( "Empty tree" );
        else
            printTree( root );
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to get element field.
     * @param t the node.
     * @return the element field or null if t is null.
     */
    private Comparable elementAt( BinaryNode t )
    {
        return t == null ? null : t.element;
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to insert into a subtree.
     * @param x the item to insert.
     * @param t the node that roots the tree.
     * @return the new root.
     */
    private BinaryNode insert( Comparable<T> x, BinaryNode<T> t )
    {
/* 1*/      if( t == null )
            {
/* 2*/          t = new BinaryNode( x, null, null );

                t.parent = null;
                if (t.left != null)
                    t.left.parent = t;
                if (t.right != null)
                    t.right.parent = t;
            }
/* 3*/      else if( x.compareTo((T)t.element ) < 0 )
            {
/* 4*/          t.left = insert( x, t.left );
                t.left_count++;
                t.left.parent = t;

            }
/* 5*/      else if( x.compareTo((T) t.element ) > 0 )
            {
/* 6*/          t.right = insert( x, t.right );
                t.right.parent = t;

            }
/* 7*/      else
/* 8*/          ;  // Duplicate; do nothing
/* 9*/      return t;
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to remove from a subtree.
     * @param x the item to remove.
     * @param t the node that roots the tree.
     * @return the new root.
     */
    private BinaryNode remove( Comparable<T> x, BinaryNode<T> t )
    {
        if( t == null )
            return t;   // Item not found; do nothing
        if( x.compareTo( (T)t.element ) < 0 )
        {
            t.left = remove( x, t.left );

        }
        else if( x.compareTo( (T)t.element ) > 0 )
        {
            t.right = remove( x, t.right );


        }
        else if( t.left != null && t.right != null ) // Two children
        {
            t.element = findMin( t.right ).element;
            t.right = remove( t.element, t.right );


        }
        else
            t = ( t.left != null ) ? t.left : t.right;
        if (t != null)
        {
            if (t.left != null)
                t.left.parent = t;
            if (t.right != null)
                t.right.parent = t;
        }
        return t;
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to find the smallest item in a subtree.
     * @param t the node that roots the tree.
     * @return node containing the smallest item.
     */
    private BinaryNode<T> findMin( BinaryNode<T> t )
    {
        if( t == null )
            return null;
        else if( t.left == null )
            return t;
        return findMin( t.left );
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to find the largest item in a subtree.
     * @param t the node that roots the tree.
     * @return node containing the largest item.
     */
    private BinaryNode<T> findMax( BinaryNode<T> t )
    {
        if( t != null )
            while( t.right != null )
                t = t.right;

        return t;
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to find an item in a subtree.
     * @param x is item to search for.
     * @param t the node that roots the tree.
     * @return node containing the matched item.
     */
    private BinaryNode find( Comparable<T> x, BinaryNode<T> t )
    {
        if( t == null )
            return null;
        if( x.compareTo( (T)t.element ) < 0 )
            return find( x, t.left );
        else if( x.compareTo( (T)t.element ) > 0 )
            return find( x, t.right );
        else
            return t;    // Match
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to print a subtree in sorted order.
     * @param t the node that roots the tree.
     */
    private void printTree( BinaryNode<T> t )
    {
        if( t != null )
        {
            printTree( t.left );
            System.out.println( t.element );
            printTree( t.right );
        }
    }


  @Deprecated
 //Updates nodes current parent
 // Unfortunaetly to expensive as it is O(N) algorithm. 
 // Therefore it sadly didn't make the final cut and is a deprecated method can be removed in the near future.
 private void update(BinaryNode<T> t) 
 {
     if (t != null)
     {
         if (t.left != null)
            t.left.parent = t;
         if (t.right != null)
            t.right.parent = t;
         update(t.left);
         update(t.right);
     }
 }


 /** 
 * Returns an iterator pointing just before the 
 * item in the tree with the lowest value. 
 * 
 **/

 public Iterator<T> iterator() 
 {
     return new MyIterator();
 }


 /** 
 * Returns the element at a given index position. 
 * Throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException if the item is not found. 
 * Runs in average O(log N) time. 
 */ 
 public T get( int index ) 
 {
      return get(root, index);
 }

 private T get(BinaryNode<T> root, int index)
 {
     if (root == null) return null;
     if (root.left_count == index-1) return (T)root.element;
     if (root.left_count < index) return get(root.right, index - (root.left_count + 1));
     else
     {
         return get(root.left, index);
     }
 }


 /** 
 * Returns all elements falling within a range of indexes. 
 * The range is inclusive 
 */ 

 public Collection<T> getRange( int first, int last ) 
 {
     ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
     for(int i = first; i <= last; i++)
     {
         list.add(get(i));
     }
     return list;
 }

 /** 
 * Prints the tree in level-order, which means the root is printed, 
 * then all nodes at level 2, then nodes at level 3, and so on. 
 */ 
 public void printLevelOrder( ) throws InterruptedException  
 {
     Queue Q = new Queue();
     Q.enqueue(root);
     while(!Q.isEmpty())
     {
        BinaryNode<T> node =  (BinaryNode<T>)Q.dequeue();
        System.out.print(node.element + ",");
        if (node.left != null)
            Q.enqueue(node.left);
        if (node.right != null)
            Q.enqueue(node.right);
     }
     System.out.println();
 }






 private class MyIterator implements Iterator<T>
 {

        private BinaryNode<T> nextNode = null;
        private boolean firstCall;
        public MyIterator()
        {
            nextNode = BinarySearchTree.this.findMin(root);
            firstCall = true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            return !nextNode.equals(BinarySearchTree.this.findMax(root));
        }

        @Override
        public T next()
        {
            if (firstCall)
            {
                firstCall = false;
                return (T)nextNode.element;
            }
            if (!hasNext())
                   throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Cannot manke another next() call!!!!?!");
            BinaryNode<T> node = successor(nextNode); 
            nextNode = node;
            return (T)node.element;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove()
        {
            BinarySearchTree.this.remove(nextNode.element);
        }

        /** 
        * Returns the next value in the sequence, starting at the 
        * node pointed to by the input parameter. This method 
        * is used by the iterator. 
        */ 
        private BinaryNode<T> successor( BinaryNode<T> p )
        {
              BinaryNode<T> n = p.right;
              if (n != null)
              {
                  return BinarySearchTree.this.findMin(n);
              }
              else
              {
                 n = p.parent;
                 while(n != null && p == n.right)
                 {
                     p = n;
                     n = n.parent;
                 }
                 return n;
              }
        }


 }



      /** The tree root. */
    private BinaryNode<T> root;



    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws InterruptedException
    {

        BinarySearchTree<String> t = new BinarySearchTree<>();
        String[] array = { "Harry","Maria","Bob","Dan","Sue","Ann","Jose" }; 

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                t.insert(array[i]);
        print( t );

        System.out.print("Level order: ");
        t.printLevelOrder();
        System.out.println("\n");

        System.out.printf( "The value at index %d is %s\n", 0, t.get(0) );
        System.out.printf( "The value at index %d is %s\n", 2, t.get(2) );
        System.out.printf( "The value at index %d is %s\n", 6, t.get(6) );

        System.out.print("\nRemoving ");
        for( int i = 1; i < array.length; i+= 2 ) {
                System.out.print(array[i] + ", ");
                t.remove( array[i] );
        }
        System.out.println();   

        System.out.println("\nTree contents after removing elements:");
        print( t );

        // verify that the get method still works
        System.out.printf( "The value at index %d is %s\n", 0, t.get(0) );
        System.out.printf( "The value at index %d is %s\n", 2, t.get(2) );
        System.out.printf( "The value at index %d is %s\n", 3, t.get(3) );


    }

    public static void print( BinarySearchTree<? extends Comparable<?>> t ) 
    { 

        for(Object x : t) 
        System.out.print(x + ", "); 
        System.out.println("\n"); 
    } 

 private static void test1() throws InterruptedException 
 { 
        BinarySearchTree<Integer> t = new BinarySearchTree<>( ); 
        int[] array = { 20, 10, 11, 30, 2, 29, 33, 28, 17, 4 }; 
         for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
             t.add(array[i]);

        print( t ); // demonstrate the iterator 

        System.out.println("Level order"); 
        t.printLevelOrder(); 

        System.out.printf( "The value at index %d is %d\n", 0, t.get(0) ); 
        System.out.printf( "The value at index %d is %d\n", 1, t.get(1) ); 
        System.out.printf( "The value at index %d is %d\n", 2, t.get(2) ); 
        System.out.printf( "The value at index %d is %d\n", 3, t.get(3) ); 
        System.out.printf( "The value at index %d is %d\n", 8, t.get(8) ); 
        System.out.printf( "The value at index %d is %d\n", 9, t.get(9) ); 

        System.out.print("\nRemoving "); 
        for( int i = 1; i < array.length; i+= 2 ) { 
        System.out.print(array[i] + ", "); 
        t.remove( array[i] ); 
        } 
        System.out.println(); 

        System.out.println("\nTree contents after removing elements:"); 
        print( t ); 

        // verify that the get method still works 
        System.out.printf( "The value at index %d is %d\n", 0, t.get(0) ); 
        System.out.printf( "The value at index %d is %d\n", 1, t.get(1) ); 
        System.out.printf( "The value at index %d is %d\n", 2, t.get(2) ); 
        System.out.printf( "The value at index %d is %d\n", 3, t.get(3) ); 
        } 




}
```

Here is the code for the get method:

```
 /** 
 * Returns the element at a given index position. 
 * Throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException if the item is not found. 
 * Runs in average O(log N) time. 
 */ 
 public T get( int index ) 
 {
      return get(root, index);
 }

 private T get(BinaryNode<T> root, int index)
 {
     if (root == null) return null;
     if (root.left_count == index-1) return (T)root.element;
     if (root.left_count < index) return get(root.right, index - (root.left_count + 1));
     else
     {
         return get(root.left, index);
     }
 }
```

Here is the incorrect output:

> Ann, Bob, Dan, Harry, Jose, Maria, Sue,
>
> Level order: Harry,Bob,Maria,Ann,Dan,Jose,Sue,
>
> The value at index 0 is null 
>   The value at index 2 is Bob 
>   The value at index 6 is Maria
>
> Removing Maria, Dan, Ann,
>
> Tree contents after removing elements: Bob, Harry, Jose, Sue,
>
> The value at index 0 is null The value at index 2 is Bob The value at
>   index 3 is null

As you can see index has a bunch of nulls and invalid elements. Everything else is correctly outputted. So get is 100% failing, as I already wrote get initially using a naive method. But the professor wants it to be O(log(N)).

As this is a homework assignment, for my Data Structures course please refrain from giving fully working code. All I want is some guidance, I understand it is wrong (judging from the output) but I fail to understand why. I also still don't fully understand the algorithm which makes it harder for me to debug the code. I assume that node.left_count is correct (but it may be wrong), so I believe the bug is in the get method. As I might be misunderstanding something with the algorithm.

## Update

If I change this if (root.left_count == index-1) return (T)root.element; to this
if (root.left_count == index) return (T)root.element;

I get this output:

> ```
> Ann, Bob, Dan, Harry, Jose, Maria, Sue, 
>
> Level order: Harry,Bob,Maria,Ann,Dan,Jose,Sue,
>
>
> The value at index 0 is Ann
> The value at index 2 is Dan
> The value at index 6 is Sue
>
> Removing Maria, Dan, Ann, 
>
> Tree contents after removing elements:
> Bob, Harry, Jose, Sue, 
>
> The value at index 0 is null
> The value at index 2 is null
> The value at index 3 is Harry
> ```

Comment: You posted hopelessly too much code. Please narrow it down to a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Dukeling It is tested and how it could be unreadable? There is a lot of helpful comments. Believe me I ain't new here as you can see from my profile so don't assume I am new. I even gave the method that is most likely giving the issue. Including output and pointing out what my problem most likely is. So why you propose to close it? The question is not vague neither is my explanation. If you want me to add something please be more specific. But just saying you posted to much code is a little vague on your part.

Comment: How is saying you posted too much code vague? You have 500+ lines of code. That, in my book, is hopelessly too much (well, anything above like 50-200, with exceptions). I didn't assume you're new, but the fact that you're not concerns me. I'm honestly not going to work through all your code and point out which things are not relevant to your question and what you could replace them with, because, well, that kind of defeats the point, which is - I don't want to work through (or see) 500+ lines of code in a question, and I don't think a question with that much code is good for the site.

Comment: Well your link you provided doesn't mention a limit on lines of code. Nobody is forcing you to read all those lines of code. Its not even a lot I have seen problems with more complex code in SO its not even that complex its as clean and compact as it can be. So if you don't have anything else to say then I suggest you don't write all. I value your opinion I just don't value that you proposed to close the question as I didn't violate anything in that article. Again it doesn't say what is long or short. 500 lines of code is pretty short especially when most of it is whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (root.left_count == index-1) return (T)root.element;
```

should be

```
if (root.left_count == index) return (T)root.element;
```

As you will see immediately. 0 left items, index 0, 3 left items, index 3.
This assumes the convention starting indexing from 0.

*Tip: **Never believe the specification.***

Comment: I agree with the tip I was skeptical and still am. But I am sticking with what the professor sent to the classmates. By the way I am getting wrong output. Yes I actually tried that. I will post an update .